# What are angular nodes?

Tags: physical-chemistry, orbitals

I know that a radial node is a value of $r$ where the probability of finding an electron is zero, and nodal planes are planes where the probability of finding an electron is zero, but I haven't been able to find a good definition of an angular node. What are they exactly?

Comment: Nodal _everything_ are places where probability of finding an electron is zero. Some of them are planes, some are not.

Comment: http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/8655/angular-and-radial-nodes I typed a new answer to that question. I hope it answers yours sufficiently as well.